# Merge results from multiple columns into single ones

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a  data sheet something like the one below: The first column is a list of items, and these items are matched to different Categories: A, B...

```
Items      Category A Category A Category A Category B Category B
Item   1      x            x                    x 
Item   2      x                       x                         
Item   3                   x          x         x           x
Item   4      x                       x                     x
```

On the different sheet, I am trying to consolidate results, I have the same structure just with unique category columns this time, and I would like to check for each item, whether I have any "x" mentioned for this category and if yes then put "x", so the result from the above should look like below:

```
Items      Category A  Category B 
Item   1      x            x 
Item   2      x                   
Item   3      x            x        
Item   4      x            x
```

Any idea how the formulate would work here?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `D7`:

```
=LET(a,UNIQUE(B1:F1,1),HSTACK(A1:A5,VSTACK(a,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:A5),COUNTA(a),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(SUM((A2:A5=INDEX(A2:A5,x,1))*(B2:F5="x")*(B1:F1=INDEX(a,1,y))),"x",""))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, @jvdV; the thing is, I already have my structure with the list of items and unique categories in my results sheet, so I don't need to extract those again; I just need to extract the "x” part.

Comment: So if you have to start in `B2` use `=IF(SUM(($A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$F$5="x")*(Sheet1!$B$1:$F$1=B$1)),"x","")` and drag right and down. If need be use `SUMPRODUCT()` depending on your version of Excel @elv